# Extract option values and text in a selectbox using regexp

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I have the code for a number of HTML selectboxes stored in a database, e. g.:

```
<select id="appearance_body_style" class="cls_selectbox"> 
 <option value="">-- select --</option> 
 <option value="underweight">untergewichtig</option>
 <option value="slim">schlank</option>
 <option value="athletic">athletisch</option>
 <option value="average">durchschnittlich</option> 
 <option value="full_figured">mollig</option> 
 <option value="overweight">übergewichtig</option> 
</select>
```

I need two regular expressions:

- one to get the string from the value attribute.
- one to get the string between the options tags.

Everything needs to be in a loop to extract those two strings line for line.

Comment: We have hundreds of questions asking how to parse X from HTML question already. Please do research and show us you put some effort trying to solve this on your own before asking. We are not code monkeys.

Comment: you can use https://gist.github.com/1358174 and for a) `//option/@value` and for b) `//option`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$match = array();
preg_match_all( '~<option value="([^"]+)">([^<>]+)</option>~', $html, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r( $match);
```

See also php documentation for [preg_match_all](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have more luck with something like this:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/